# Calling external API and library functions from Schematron in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, schematron

With proper `<sch:ns/>` declared for `cts` and `dohickey`, I can call MarkLogic API functions such as `cts:*` from compiled Schematron as follows (which is *awesome*, by the way):

```
<sch:rule context="dohickey:thingummy">
    <sch:let name="this-id" value="dohickey:meta/dohickey:id/string()"/>
    <sch:let name="known-ids" value="cts:element-values(xs:QName('dohickey:id'))"/>
    <sch:report test="$this-id = $known-ids">Warning: This id is known, and that's a business error</sch:report>
</sch:rule>
```

(Please ignore that the `$known-ids` variable would be optimized to lock down on a single value in real life, instead of returning them all---for the sake of the example)

Now I'd like to include custom XQuery modules in my Schematron in the same way that I can call `cts:*` in the example above, and in the same way I can call XQuery library functions when working with raw XSLT and MarkLogic XSLT/XQuery integration by defining, e.g., an `xsl:stylesheet/@extension-element-prefixes` value, followed by an appropriate `<xdmp:import-module/>`.

Example: I'd like to do the following:

```
<sch:rule context="dohickey:thingummy">
    <sch:let name="this-id" value="dohickey:meta/dohickey:id/string()"/>
    <sch:let name="is-flagged-for-revision" value="mycustommodule:is-flagged-for-revision($this-id)"/>
    <sch:report test="$is-flagged-for-revision">Warning: This id has been flagged for revision</sch:report>
</sch:rule>
```

Question: is there currently a way to get MarkLogic's `schematron:put` compilation behavior to include custom XQuery module imports, analogous to MarkLogic's XSLT `<xdmp:import-module/>` support? Or should I just implement a wrapper that transforms the `schematron:put` compiled result to include what I need so it's in the compiled XSLT?

Comment: I suspect that the official Schematron XSLT's are being used under the covers, so I don't think it will support the imports. It should be easy enough to patch the XSLT's to add imports though. You could try doing it with `xdmp:node-insert-child`..

Comment: Turns out there actually is an OOTB convenient way on compilation---see accepted answer by @mads-hansen below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself, you can use the [`<xdmp:import-module>`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xslt#id_60484) instruction to import an XQuery library module into an XSLT stylesheet in MarkLogic. Once you have imported the module, any functions defined in that module are available to that stylesheet.

It is possible to incorporate foreign vocabularies in your Schematron schema. You can use that to include an `xdmp:import-module` into the compiled schema. However, you need to set the [`allow-foreign`](https://github.com/Schematron/schematron/blob/c9f354c3aa01e81273637fa13fb75ba173247f78/trunk/ant-schematron/code/resource/xslt/iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl#L180) parameter to `true` when you compile the Schematron. The default is `false`.

Within your Schematron schema, you first need to declare the namespace(s) using `sch:ns`, so that the prefixes are recognized:

```
<sch:ns prefix="search" uri="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"/>
<sch:ns prefix="xdmp" uri="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"/>
```

You add your foreign markup, such as `xdmp:import-module` to import an XQuery library module. Put the import at the root-level of you schema:

```
<xdmp:import-module namespace="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" 
  href="/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy"/>
```

You can use the imported library function(s) within your Schematron directly using the prefix defined earlier:

```
<sch:rule context="test">
  <sch:let name="estimate" value="search:estimate(search:parse(@term))"/>
  <sch:assert test="$estimate gt 0" diagnostics="d1">At least one doc should be found</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

Just make sure that when you compile the Schematron schema into an XSLT, and load it into your modules database using [`schematron:put()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/schematron:put), you set the `allow-foreign` option to `true()` as follows:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron" 
  at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";

let $params := map:map()
  => map:with('allow-foreign', fn:true())
return
  schematron:put("/mySchema.sch", $params)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, Mads---I missed the allow-foreign param on compilation. Calling custom library functions from Schematron works like a charm. (All the way back to 9.0-7, btw.)

Comment: The answer is not entirely explicit about this, but I guess those imports will have to be appended to the compiled schematron stylesheets in the modules database, like I mentioned above. But maybe @mads-hansen can confirm?

Comment: No manual workaround or post-processing necessary. Add the `<xdmp:import>` directly in the Schematron *.sch file and it will be copied into the compiled XSLT (as long as the `allow-foreign` flag is set to true)